# SSAS Order by a dimension group

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas

I'm using a Multidimensional Analysis Services ver 13, displaying results in excel pivot tables. I'm trying to divide my clients into groups using the ClientSelect table with a hierarchy based on Platform / Type, with top 20 for each type. for example below

Platform / Type

All Games

```
YTD Top Winner
YTD Most Played
YTD Most Liked
```

Chess

```
YTD Top Winner
YTD Most Played 
YTD Most Liked
```

Because the same client may appear in many lists, i am using a many to many fct table (ClientSelectMap) to join clients and ClientSelect.

This all works fine, I can display the top 20 All Games / YTD Top winners, and see their results for yesterday. But i want to display the 20 YTD Top Winners in order of the YTD wins or matches played or likes. I provide an OrderBy Attribute in the DimClientSelect table but whenever i try to associate it with the Type attribute so it becomes available for use in the OrderByAttribute field and use it to order Type, i get duplicate errors.

How do i order the returned clients in this situation? Do i have to put the orderBy in the joining table?

Thanks in advance
Hamish

[image]